# How do I consume an encrypted payload in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, webhooks, jose

I have tried to handle it using:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json",consumes= "application/jose;charset=UTF-8")
```

I get the below error:

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
> type 'application/jose;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: "application/jose;charset=UTF-8" - I've never seen this before.  Apparently neither has Spring.  Not supported out of the box.

Comment: May be your request doesn't contain the header "Content-Type: application/jose". Please check. I am able to test successfully with the annotation you have posted.

I used `curl -X POST http://localhost:3005/v1/context -H "Content-Type: application/jose" -d "abc"`

Comment: @SreeKumar Thank you for your response. My Request does contain "Content-Type: application/Jose" in header. Do you have any other external library which supports encrypted requests? I executed your command and got the same error.